# Integrate CVS repository in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cvs

Is it possible to integrate a CVS repository in Xcode?
If it is, can you give step-by-step instruction to integrate it?

Edit: if it is impossible to integrate in Xcode, does exists a free client GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found anything about integrate CVS in Xcode again.
And looking for a GUI solution I found SmartCVS but is old and IMHO it is not very user friendly.
At the end I am using Eclipse to manage the repository.